# Taking average in every half hour

Tags: vba, informix

I am using Informix database for storing data.Iam continuously running my application from 08:00AM to 04:00pm.I want to take the average in every half hour from  08:00AM till end  and generate report.I am using VBA script in my application.

If any one know how to take average in every half hour and generate report by using script.

Comment: look into `Application.OnTime`

Comment: What do you want to take an average of?

Answer (score 0):

Is this an Informix doubt, or a VBA one?
If you mean "how can I get an average in Informix", you can use (as in several other database engines, AVG function).